# Automatic Interactive shell installation script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I'm trying to create a script that runs an installation script and answer the installation questions like: "Press enter to continue", "yes/no?", "enter username:", "enter password".

My script needs to provide the answers to the other script questions.

I can't use expect because this script will run in many machines which I don't if they support exepct.

I have already tried this

```
install.sh <<!
y
username
pasword
!
```

But the install script goes to an infinite loop asking for the username

> Administrator user name => User name can't be blank, please try again
>
> Administrator user name => User name can't be blank, please try again
>
> Administrator user name => User name can't be blank, please try again

The same thing happens with the following:

```
echo "yes
username
$PASSWORD" | sh install
```

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: How is the script reading the username? If it reads from `stdin` then your code should work. Is it reading from `/dev/tty` instead? Then you need to use something like Expect, which will create a pseudo-terminal.

Comment: I don't know what they use.

Comment: It's a script, can't you just read it and see how it reads the username?

Comment: At worst interrogating `/proc` should be able to show what the process is using.

Comment: Sorry Barmar, that was stupid. I'm just changing the script to do not ask anything.